# What is the easiest way to rename all occurrences of a variable name using clang libtooling and having a namedDecl handle?

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

I want to make a program that makes abstract names for all function,variable,namespace ... and replaces the current ones.To this purpose i have used the clang libtooling documentation as well as their AST visitor example. I have found other useful tutorials
on the internet such as :
[This example of a tool that renames a function](https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-ii-libtooling-example/)
; [This example of how to write a matcher and replacer](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/07/29/ast-matchers-and-clang-refactoring-tools).
My code has lots of finders like that in the first website :

```
  virtual bool VisitVarDecl(VarDecl *func) {
errs() << func->getNameAsString()<<" ";
auto a = func->getType();
errs() << a.getAsString()<<"space";
//also tried this with no success
Twine a = Twine("works");
 func->setName(a);
return true;
```

}

So the question is how do I replace all occurences of that name in the context of that name : for example a dumb replacer based on regex would replace global and local variable with the same name but using the namedDecl handle should get me only the one detected by the visitor?

Comment: I wouldn't implement the visitor for this. `clang-rename` is good enough for what you described. check https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-rename.html

Comment: if you want some flexibility, i think ast matcher is the way to go.